# Style does not change when my component receive a new props

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to display my component when the value of the props is "true" but it's always 'display: none'.
My main component send it true or false.

```
import React                from 'react';
import Header               from '../../Header/Header';

export default class Body extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {};
}

render(){
   if(this.props.status == true){
        var BodyVisibility = {
            display: 'visible' 
        }
    }
    else {
        var BodyVisibility = {
            display: 'none'
        }
    }
    return(
            <div className='body' style={BodyVisibility}>
                <Header />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more related to Javascript than ReactJS in particular. I think you're passing `status` to your `Component` as a `string`. So, how the comparison happens when your Component sees this is:

```
if('true' == true)
```

So, the comparison happens between a `string` and `boolean`. Due to type coercion, Javascript converts both to `Number` and does the comparison. See **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)** for more details. `string` value is evaluated to `NaN` and `true` value to `1`. So the comparison after coercion is:

```
if(NaN == 1)
```

which will always give `false` hence your result.

---

In order to fix this issue you should be using both operators as string like this:

```
if(this.props.status == 'true')
```

Although, as a better practice, it's always better to use `===` for strict equality. Also you're accessing a variable outside its scope (which will work here but not a good practice). A better version of the code would be:

```
var BodyVisibility = {
    display: 'none'
}

if(this.props.status === 'true'){
    BodyVisibility.display = 'visible'
}
```